# Проверить вхождение списка в словарь. Вывести сумму ключей, объекты которых совпали с объектами в списке

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, list, словари

Цель данного кода - посчитать цену выбранных блюд(`order`). И он вполне рабочий

```
def k_oplate():
         menu = {"Овсянка":34,"Картошка":22,"Омлет с сыром":27,"Суп рисовый": 
             45,"Салат весенний": 56, "Эспрессо": 16,
             "Семга": 90,"Вареники с капустой": 37, "Беляши":12}
         order = ["Овсянка","Овсянка","Вареники с капустой"]
         summ = 0
         for dish,price in menu.items():
             for element in order:
                 if element == dish:
                     summ += price

         print(summ)
k_oplate()
```

---

Этот код делает тоже самое только выводит ответ в `textEdit`. Только вот выводит он почему - то `0`

```
def add(self):
        order = []
        self.ui.listWidget.addItem(self.ui.comboBox.currentText())
        order.append(self.ui.comboBox.currentText())
        menu = {"Овсянка":34,"Картошка":22,"Омлет с сыром":27,"Суп рисовый": 45,"Салат весенний": 56, "Эспрессо": 16,
        "Семга": 90,"Вареники с капустой": 37, "Беляши":12}
        summ = 0

        for dish,price in menu.items():
            for element in order:
                if element == dish:
                    summ += price
        self.ui.textEdit.setText(str(summ))
```

Comment: Видимо, order[] пуст.

Comment: Проверял на вождение элементов в него - он заполняется

Answer (score 0):

Я вашу идею увидел так:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class MainWindow(QWidget): 
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.ui = self
        self.menu = {"Овсянка":34, "Картошка":22, "Омлет с сыром":27,
                     "Суп рисовый": 45,"Салат весенний": 56, "Эспрессо": 16,
                     "Семга": 90,"Вареники с капустой": 37, "Беляши":12}
        self.summ = 0

        self.ui.listWidget = QListWidget()
        self.ui.listWidget.addItem("Ваш выбор : ")

        self.ui.comboBox   = QComboBox()
        self.ui.comboBox.addItems(self.menu)
        self.ui.comboBox.currentIndexChanged[str].connect(self.add)

        self.ui.textEdit   = QTextEdit("Итого к оплате:")

        self.ui.button1 = QPushButton("Печать меню.", self)
        self.ui.button1.clicked.connect(self.printMenu)
        self.ui.button2 = QPushButton("Очистить меню.", self)
        self.ui.button2.clicked.connect(self.clearMenu)

        self.grid = QGridLayout(self) 
        self.grid.addWidget(QLabel("Выберите блюдо:"), 0, 0)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.ui.comboBox, 0, 1)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.ui.listWidget, 1, 0, 1, 2)     
        self.grid.addWidget(self.ui.textEdit, 3, 0, 1, 2)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.ui.button1, 5, 0)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.ui.button2, 5, 1)


    def add(self, dish):
        price = self.menu[dish]

        self.ui.listWidget.addItem("{} : {}".format(dish, price))
        self.summ += price
        self.ui.textEdit.setText("Итого к оплате: {}".format(self.summ))

    def printMenu(self):
        print("Печатаем меню ...")

    def clearMenu(self):
        self.ui.listWidget.clear()
        self.ui.listWidget.addItem("Ваш выбор : ")
        self.summ = 0        
        self.ui.textEdit.setText("Итого к оплате:")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(300, 200)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]